# DevExpress RepositoryItemButtonEdit

Tags: devexpress

When the ellipsis button of the ButtonEdit is clicked, in the ButtonEdit's ButtonClick event I launch another form from which the user makes a choice.

That lookup form informs my original form of the chosen value.

When my original form learns the chosen value, it sets the value of the cell associated with the ButtonEdit, using SetCellValue method. However, *the value does not display until the cell loses focus*. Is there any way to cause the value to display while the cell with the ButtonEdit as its in-place RowEdit still has focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `view.ActiveEditor.EditValue`.

Comment: Looks promising. I will report back. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When handling the ButtonClick event, the sender parameter passed to the event handler represents the editor instance whose value must be changed.  So, I would like to post an additional solution showing how to set the editor's value:

```
private void repositoryItemButtonEdit1_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e) {
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit edit = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit;
    edit.EditValue = SomeValue;
}
```

Comment: The second solution wouldn't work. Why? Because in the ButtonClick event I am launching another form as a Dialog ("the lookup form").  When the user makes a choice on the lookup form, it raises an event that my original form is listening for. It is within the LookupItemChosen event that I must set the edit value, not in the ButtonClick event.

Comment: Where possible, I would favour the solution posted by DevExpress Team. A RepositoryItem should always have an "OwnerEdit" as the sender of the event, but an edit is not always in a "view".

I would also expect a lookup dialog to have a property for its selected value, instead of relying on an event within it. System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog for example has its property "FileName".